# $http() doesn't send data by method 'POST' to PHP server

Tags: php, angularjs, http, request

i got trouble when i send data by method post to a php file, here's an exemple:

```
function SimuladorService ( $http, config ) {
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;";
$http.defaults.headers.post["Accept"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

const post = function(dados) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "example.php",
        data: {
            nome:'almir',
            sobrenome: 'teste'
        },
        transformRequest : function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },

    })

}}
```

example.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

it's not return my $_POST data.

Comment: the problem is on the server side or in front-end?

Comment: i created a variable for testing for example <?php echo json_encode('test') ?> and it worked. The problem is send datas by posting method.

Comment: I've tested with postman and realized file_get_contents('php://input') at the local environment is not working. I'dont know why.

Answer (score -1):

if the problem is on the side of angular, try that code:

```
 $scope.post = function(dados){
        console.log(dados)
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "example.php",
            data: {
                nome:'almir',
                sobrenome: 'teste'
                },
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

    }
```

html:   `<button ng-click="post('dados')">click</button>`

check what you get in `console.log` if the problem continues, then it will be possible to get to the cause

Comment: it's the same thing i created. The problema is php file don't receive $_post and returning my $_POST datas.

Comment: I've tested with postman and realized file_get_contents('php://input') at the local environment is not working. I'dont know why.

Answer (score -1):

To POST data to a PHP API, simply use the defaults:

```
var data = {
    nome:'almir',
    sobrenome: 'teste'
};

function post(data) {
    var url = "example.php";
    return $http.post(url,data);
}

post(data).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data)
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    throw response;
})
```

On the PHP server side:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

With the AngularJS framework, the default is to use JSON data. It is best to avoid using url encoded data.

Comment: I've tested with postman and realized file_get_contents('php://input') at the local environment is not working. I'dont know why.

Comment: Be sure to use `Content-Type: application/json`. Don't override the AngularJS defaults.